# How to prevent the hackers to hack your site

Tags: php, security

I'm a newbie developer and the site that I developed was hacked.I'm using prepared statements so that they can't use SQL Injection but still, the site got hacked. what can I do to fully secure my site. by the way I'm using php.

Comment: Questions about securing your site would be a better fit for either [webmasters.se] or [security.se]; but to ask them there (as here) you'd need to provide sufficient details of what happened, and what you're specifically asking about. The question of how to secure your site is the topic of several multi-chapter books, which is far too broad for the subject to be adequately covered in any single answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is for specific, code-based questions, questions that can be answered rather than discussed. You'll need to do some research on general web security and if you then have a specific question, we're here to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have popular services running on your site (e.g. phpmyadmin) put it in a folder where it is not commonly found - e.g. dont have a url/phymyadmin on your site.

Ensure all your error messages are not available publicly. This is something that many web 'hackers' will first use to glean information about the versions of software you are using. They will then search for vulnerabilties in those specific versions.

Use strong passwords everywhere, despite all the complexity and advancements around us today, one of the most common way for hackers to gain access to a system is to brute force a password.

Ensure all your permissions are correctly setup on your server. If someone does get into your server, they will not have such an easy task if you have permissions setup correctly on all the executable scripts etc.

Ensure you are not storing log files in public places.

If you really want to get an good insight into how to make your site hackproof, I would suggest taking a 'hacking' course on udemy or the like, many 'ethical' hackers teach you how to 'ethically hack' for $20 - $30 in these courses, and you can learn alot about how to secure your own system in the process.

Finally you can't prevent hackers from hacking your site, but you can make it harder for them to do so, and therefore minimise the probability that your site will be hacked. Even facebook [see here](https://www.facebook.com/BugBounty/) still have open bounties (that are claimed) for hackers that can find loop holes through to their servers, or vulnerabilities in their code etc.